# Searching for an exact match that contains brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am reading in lines from a file each of which are formatted like this:

```
array_name[0]
array_name[1]
```

How can I do an exact match on this string in python?  I've tried this:

```
if re.match(line, "array_name[0]")
```

but it seems to match all the time without taking the parts in bracket ([0], [1], etc.) into account

Comment: If you look for a literal string, don't use a regex.

Answer (score 1):

[`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) from the `re` module is a useful tool for automatically escaping characters that the regex engine considers special. From the docs:

> `re.escape(pattern)`
>
> Escape all the characters in pattern except ASCII
>   letters and numbers. This is useful if you want to match an arbitrary
>   literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

```
In [1]: re.escape("array_name[0]")
Out[1]: 'array_name\\[0\\]'
```

Also, you've reversed the order of your arguments. You'll need your pattern to come first, followed by the text you want to match:

```
re.match(re.escape("array_name[0]"), line)
```

Example:

```
In [2]: re.match(re.escape("array_name[0]"), 'array_name[0] in a line')
Out[2]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='array_name[0]'>
```